# Is this $x$-$t$ graph possible? Is the distance decreasing over time in this graph?

Tags: kinematics, time, terminology, distance, displacement

I have read in a Book:

[image] [image]

But I think it is possible as a Negative Velocity and Positive Acceleration:
[image]

Reference:

1. SL Arora Physics Class 11, Pg No. 152.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your “impossible” graph shows distance, while your counterexample shows the vector displacement relative to some origin.

Think about a car with an odometer and a GPS.  You can make your total vector displacement for a trip equal to zero, by driving back to your starting point, and comparing your GPS starting point to your GPS endpoint. But you cannot make the distance traveled during the trip zero, unless you don’t go.  The number on the odometer only ever goes up.

Comment: As an alternative to the non-decreasing nature of the odometer reading, one could refer to the wear on the tires. Neither returning to start point nor driving backwards will undo the wear. Distance travelled is measured by tire wear.

Answer (score 3):

The velocity should be displacement over time, while the speed is the distance over time. In contrast to displacement, which is a vector and could have a negative sign, the distance is the length through which an object travels over a period of time and could only be positive.

Comment: So here the difference between scalar and vector quantities is considered importantly?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Actually, the distance is the path that an objective has run through. As time goes on, it can only increase (or accumulate). Referring to the exercises regarding distance, displacement, speed, and velocity would give deeper understanding on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Think of running to catch a bus.
That could be a graph of distance from the bus against time indicating a slowing down with fatigue as one gets closer to the bus.

Answer (score 0):

We have to clarify some things and denote another one. Firstly it is obvious that we cannot have a time-distance graph as above, because the distance function $d:I\subset [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$, where $I$ is a time interval, is non decreasing (the above graph is decreasing). But the time-distance graph *is not* a $t$-$x$ graph. The last one is a time-*position* graph, which of course can be as $x=\frac1t, t>0$. Finally displacement in $\Bbb R^n$ *is* a vector function of two variables, which for every $t\in I$ and every time increment $Δt\in \Bbb R$ such that $t+Δt\in I$ assigns a vector $Δ\mathbf r(t, Δt):=\mathbf r(t+Δt)-\mathbf r(t)$. As every such function, $Δ\mathbf r$ has a graph in $\Bbb R^{n+2}$, the set $\{(t, Δt, Δ\mathbf r(t, Δt))\in \Bbb R^{n+2}|t, t+Δt\in I\}$.

PS. More precisely a distance function is a function $\hat d:A\times A\to [0,\infty)$, which gives the distance $d(a,a')$ of two points $a, a'\in A$. Here we have arranged this definition by setting the variable of time and supposing that function $d$ gives us the distance covered by a moving point from the beggining of its motion (when, let us say, $t=0$) til some time $t>0$. So we have $d(t):=\hat d (x(0), x(t)):I\to [0,\infty)$. (By convention we consider $x=x(t)$ as an injective function)